# Bootstrap 5 Table Column Spacing

Tags: html, django

Need help with formatting a Bootstrap table column spacing. The data shown is populated dynamically. The Add New on the header is a clickable link.
The Departments table has only one field but each row should have to clickable link buttons namely Edit and Delete as shown. My challenge is getting the spacing between all three columns (Department Name, Edit and Delete) to look more or less like the Process table.

Kindly help correct the below code for the Departments table to render like the Process table
[image]
[image]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-left">Departments</div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 text-right">
                <a class="link-dark text-light" href="{% url 'add_department' %}">Add New </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Department Name</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for department in all_departments %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{department.department_name}}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="link-primary" href="{% url 'update_department' department.id %}">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td class="w-10">
                <a class="link-danger" href="{% url 'delete_department' department.id %}">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-left">Departments</div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 text-right">
                <a class="link-dark text-light" href="{% url 'add_department' %}">Add New </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Department Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for department in all_departments %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{department.department_name}}</td>
            <td>
                <div style="display: inline-flex;">
                    <a class="link-primary" href="{% url 'update_department' department.id %}">Edit</a>
                    <a class="link-danger" style="margin-left: 8px;" href="{% url 'delete_department' department.id %}">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```